# Transformation of a Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems

$$L(\lambda,\mu,\dot{\lambda},\dot{\mu})=\frac{m}{2}(\lambda^2+\mu^2)(\dot{\lambda}^2+\dot{\mu}^2)-\alpha \lambda^2\mu^2,$$

I'm supposed to express this Lagrangian through

$x=\lambda^2-\mu^2$

$y=2\lambda\mu$

My first thought was to use

$x+\mu^2=\lambda^2$

by putting it into the second equation but then I get:

$y=2\mu\sqrt(x+\mu^2)$

and don´t know how to proceed.

Comment: I think this may help $(\lambda+i\mu)^2=iy+x$

Comment: I think if you write rhs in polar expersion  and take the sqrt of both sides, then take derivative respect to to both sides. then calculate the amplitude of both sides you will get the quadtratic derivative term in your lagrangian.

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/446166/2451

Comment: solve the equation for $\mu^2$ ans $\lambda^2$ you get 
$\mu^2=-1/2\,x+1/2\,\sqrt {{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}}$
and
$\lambda^2={\frac {{y}^{2}}{-2\,x+2\,\sqrt {{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}}}}$

Comment: you can check it that this is the  a solution of $x=\lambda^2-\mu^2$ and 

$y=2\,\lambda\mu$.  I use symbolic program to find the solution

Comment: This is how you get the solution:

$\lambda^2-\mu^2=x$ so $\lambda=\sqrt{x-\mu^2}$

$2\lambda\,\mu=y\quad \mapsto$
$2\sqrt{x-\mu^2}=y $  -> solution for $\mu$

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer that physshyp had in mind but felt like not writing down. Define the complex variables $\zeta = \lambda + i\, \mu$ and $z = x + i\, y$. Then
\begin{align}\zeta^2 =& (\lambda + i\, \mu)^2=  (\lambda + i\, \mu)(\lambda + i\, \mu) \\
=& \lambda^2 + i\, \lambda\, \mu + i \, \mu \, \lambda + (i\, \mu)^2 =  \lambda^2 + 2\, i\, \lambda\, \mu  - \, \mu^2 \\
=& (\lambda^2 - \mu^2) + i (2 \, \lambda \, \mu)
 \end{align} Consequently, since
\begin{align}
&x = \lambda^2 - \mu^2\\
&y = 2\, \lambda \mu
\end{align}
we have
$$z = x + i\, y = (\lambda^2 - \mu^2) + i (2 \, \lambda \, \mu) =  (\lambda + i\, \mu)^2 = \zeta^2$$
So in complex numbers, $$z = \zeta^2$$
Now,  it is easy to differentiate the change of variables and get
$$\dot{z} = 2\, \zeta\, \dot{\zeta}$$ Then, by taking absolute value squared of complex numbers
$$|\dot{z}|^2 = 4\, |\zeta|^2\, |\dot{\zeta}|^2$$ If you expand in real coordinates, recalling the definition of absolute value squared of complex numbers
$$\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^{2}  = |\dot{z}|^2 = 4\, |\zeta|^2\, |\dot{\zeta}|^2 = 4 \, (\lambda^2 + \zeta^2)\,(\dot{\lambda}^2 + \dot{\zeta}^2)$$ The latter expression is the first term of the Lagrangian and combined with the fact that $y = 2\, \lambda\, \mu$ we get the desired change of variables in the Lagrangian function
$$L = \frac{m}{2}\, (\lambda^2 + \zeta^2)\,(\dot{\lambda}^2 + \dot{\zeta}^2) - \alpha\, (\lambda \, \mu)^2 = \frac{m}{2}\,\frac{1}{4}\, (\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^{2}) - \alpha \frac{1}{4}\, y^2 =   \frac{m}{8}\, (\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^{2}) - \frac{\alpha}{4}\, y^2$$